# CKeditor - Inline events and callbacks

Tags: jquery, html, coffeescript, ckeditor

Im using ckeditor to edit inline text. the problem Im finding is that I dont see a defenate way of seeing events when ckeditor is "closed" or hidden again. The normal behaviour would be to have an element with **contenteditable** set to **true** and this would prevoke the editor once the use clicks on it.

What I want is to initiate the editor by a custom event, like a double click, and once the editor is "closed"/hidden, I want to remove the ckeditor instance from the element so that it becomes "normal" again. But I dont see that anywhere, sure you can use a .blur() event, but I dont think that is a great idea.

So currently what Im doing is to listen for a dblclick event and then:

```
edit: (e)  =>
    f = $(e.currentTarget)
    f.attr "contenteditable", true
    id = f.attr("id")
    $("##{id}").draggable({ disabled: true })
    $("##{id}").resizable({ disabled: true })
    if CKEDITOR.instances[id]
        CKEDITOR.instances[id].destroy();
    editor = CKEDITOR.inline id
    $(e.currentTarget).focus()


element.blur((el) =>
    f =  $(el.currentTarget)
    CKEDITOR.instances[f.attr("id")].destroy();
    f.removeClass 'cke_focus'
    f.addClass 'cke_editable'
```

*I would love if there is a native callback thats you know the ckeditr is now hidden, perhaps Im missing it??*

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is what I did after reading the docs if any one wondered about this. Keep in mind this is a backbone.js app:

```
({
  edit: (function(_this) {
    return function(e) {
      var editor, f, id, o_html, pk;
      f = $(e.currentTarget);
      f.attr("contenteditable", true);
      id = f.attr("id");
      pk = f.data("pk");
      $("#" + id).draggable({
        disabled: true
      });
      $("#" + id).resizable("destroy");
      editor = CKEDITOR.inline(id);
      o_html = "";
      editor.on("dataReady", function() {
        return editor.focus();
      });
      editor.on("focus", function() {
        return o_html = f[0].innerHTML;
      });
      return editor.on("blur", function(e) {
        var n_html, view;
        console.log(o_html);
        n_html = f[0].innerHTML;
        if (o_html !== n_html) {
          console.log("update data on server");
        }
        editor.destroy();
        $("#" + id).draggable({
          disabled: false
        });
        view = new PageView;
        return view.initResizable(id);
      });
    };
  })(this)
});
```